# combine columns of SQLite3 SELECT-statement

Tags: android, sqlite

i need something like

```
SELECT (Name & ', ' & Firstname) AS Test FROM Person;
```

which returns something like

```
Simpson, Homer
Simpson, Bart
...
```

in the column 'Test'.

Is it possible to create such a statement in SQLite3 (for android developing).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the || operator:

```
SELECT (Name || ', ' || Firstname) AS Test FROM Person;
```